Azure IoT hub initial devicetwin not being set correctly
I have defined an Azure IoT DPS, with an enrollment group, that calls a Custom allocation policy function, this function should set initialDeviceTwin tags, I have tried to implement this function as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-allocation-policies
With TwinCollection as the type for the tags - that did not work i.e no DeviceTwin tags was set, then I changed the implementation to:
    [Function("DeviceIoTHubAllocationFunc")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post")]  HttpRequest req)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    
        // Get registration ID of the device
        string regId = data?.deviceRuntimeContext?.registrationId;
    
        string message = "Uncaught error";
        bool fail = false;
    
        _logger.LogInformation("Request.Body:...");
        _logger.LogInformation(requestBody);
    
        ResponseObj obj = new ResponseObj();
        Response response = null;
        //ProvisioningServiceResponse response = null;
    
        if (regId == null)
        {
            message = "Registration ID not provided for the device.";
            _logger.LogInformation("Registration ID : NULL");
            fail = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("RegID");
            _logger.LogInformation(regId);
    
            string[] hubs = data?.linkedHubs?.ToObject<string[]>();
    
            // Must have hubs selected on the enrollment
            if (hubs == null)
            {
                message = "No hub group defined for the enrollment.";
                _logger.LogInformation("linkedHubs : NULL");
                fail = true;
            }
    
            _logger.LogInformation("Before get IoTHubModel");
            _logger.LogInformation(regId);
            var model = _repository.GetBySerialNumber(regId);
            _logger.LogInformation("After get IoTHubModel");
            _logger.LogInformation(model.HubHostName);
    
            
            if (model is not null && hubs.Any(h => h.Equals(model.HubHostName)))
            {
                
                response = new Response(model.HubHostName);
    
                response.initialTwin.tags = new JObject
                {
                    ["enrolled"] = model.Enrolled,
                    ["regional"] = "eus2",
                };
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Unknown hubhost";
                _logger.LogInformation($"Expected Hub host name : {model?.HubHostName ?? "NULL"}");
                fail = true;
            }
        }
    
    
        _logger.LogInformation("\nResponse");
        _logger.LogInformation((response.iotHubHostName != null) ?   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response) : message);
    
        return (fail)
            ? new BadRequestObjectResult(message)
            : (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(response);            
    }
    
    
    public class Response
    {
        public Response(string hostName)
        {
            iotHubHostName = hostName;
            initialTwin = new ResponseTwin();
        }
    
        public string iotHubHostName { get; set; }
        public ResponseTwin initialTwin { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class ResponseTwin
    {
        public ResponseTwin()
        {
            properties = new ResponseProperties();
        }
    
        public dynamic tags { get; set; }
        public ResponseProperties properties { get; set; } // contains desired properties
    }
    
    public class ResponseProperties
    {
        public dynamic desired { get; set; }
    }
    


The log output from the function was:
Request: "..........., initialTwin":{"tags":{},"properties":{"desired":{}}}
Response: {"iotHubHostName":"MYHUB.azure-devices.net","initialTwin":{"tags":{"enrolled":true,"region":"eus2"},"properties":{"desired":null}}}
When I inspect the device twin the following tags are set:
    "tags": {
        "enrolled": [],
        "region": []
    },

What am I doing wrong - and any guesses why the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared.TwinState and TwinCollection doesn't work
Thanks
Described in the sections above

are you using azure iotdps with azure iot hub? How you are connecting with code ?

Apparently this actually works: result = new
{
iotHubHostName = $"{model.HubHostName}",
initialTwin = new
{
tags = new {
enrolled = $"{model.Enrolled}",
region = "eus2",
},
properties = new
{
desired = new
{
PropOne = "2345",
PropTwo = "6789"
}
}
}
}; - Has enybody actually got TwinState/TwinCollection from the SDK to wor?

you can set the tags with below var connectionString = "your connection string"; var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString); var query = registryManager.CreateQuery("SELECT * FROM devices", 100); while (query.HasMoreResults){ var twins = await query.GetNextAsTwinAsync(); foreach (var twin in twins){twin.Tags = new TwinCollection(); twin.Tags["location"] = "Building A"; twin.Tags["temperature"] = "72F"; await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);log.LogInformation($"Tags: {twin.Tags}");}}await registryManager.CloseAsync();

The issue with device twin tags being null lies in how you're constructing and setting the initial device twin tags in the Azure Function.
I followed this MSDOC to implement a custom allocation policy in Azure Functions for Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service (DPS).
The below code is to create an individual enrollment in DPS for the device, specifying initial twin properties (tags and desired properties. TpmAttestation token from this link.

         Attestation attestation = new TpmAttestation("");

                    // Create individual enrollment with initial twin properties
                    var individualEnrollment = new IndividualEnrollment(regId, attestation)
                    {
                        DeviceId = "sampath", // Set your device ID
                        Capabilities = new DeviceCapabilities { IotEdge = false }, // Example of capabilities
                        InitialTwinState = new TwinState(
                            tags: new TwinCollection
                            {
                                ["enrolled"] = model.Enrolled,
                                ["regional"] = "eus2"
                            },
                            desiredProperties: new TwinCollection
                            {
                                ["Brand"] = "Contoso",
                                ["Model"] = "SSC4",
                                ["Color"] = "White"
                            })
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        // Create or update the individual enrollment
                        var provisioningServiceClient = ProvisioningServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(provisioningConnectionString);
                        IndividualEnrollment result = await provisioningServiceClient.CreateOrUpdateIndividualEnrollmentAsync(individualEnrollment);
                        log.LogInformation($"Created or updated enrollment: {result.RegistrationId}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.LogError($"Failed to create or update enrollment: {ex.Message}");
                        fail = true;
                        message = $"Failed to create or update enrollment: {ex.Message}";
                    }
                }




Follow this  SO  and MSDOC for getting and update data of device twin from Azure IOT Hub.
